# Really painful to run GWTP in Maven

Tags: gwt, maven, gwt-platform

I've been struggling all day to run `GWTP` with `Maven`, essentially I created a `GWTP` gwt application using the Eclipse plugin. And added a simple welcome presenter. Tried it without maven and it works well running from eclipse.

However when I convert it to a maven project (I'm using m2eclipse plugin) everything breaks. So I added the required dependencies and the gwtp dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- MVP component -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwtp-all</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

However when I try to run it I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
```

Any ideas why its quite hard to make GWTP with maven.

Comment: The error says GWT compiler cannot find the source code for EventBus which must be included in gwt jars (gwt-user I think). For this to work, not only you need the dependencies, but your GWT module declaration must say "I need another GWT module found in this place". Can you show us your gwt-module declaration (.gwt.xml file)?

Comment: sure here's my gwt.xml file: http://pastebin.com/RCx55n19

Comment: Well, your module includes user, wich in turn includes event... so it seems EventBus code is available. That's not the problem. I'm sorry.

Comment: Are you including gwt-user as a dependency right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be missing the gwt-user dependency. Here is my maven pom.xml for an GWTP project:

```
<properties>
    <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
    <gwtp.version>0.7</gwtp.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
   <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
   <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwtp-mvp-client</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Dispatch component -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-client</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> <!-- Remove for GWTP 0.5.1 and earlier -->
</dependency>
<!-- Tester component -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwtp-tester</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In case you use the newest gwtp 0.7 be aware that they switched from the depreciated classes in `com.google.gwt.event.shared` to `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared`.

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/PortingV1#V0.7) for more details.